# Store an SQLite database on Google Drive Android

Tags: android, sqlite

Is it possible to store an SQLite database on Google drive (or something similar) and read the data straight from Google drive? If so how can this be accomplished?

I'm currently downloading the database to external storage each time my app turns on then reading the data but have found this causes a few issues on different devices.
The database changes daily so I don't want to store the database in internal storage.

Comment: I feel like hosting a SQL-like server would be more useful when you've reached the point where you want to move a SQLite file to cloud storage

Comment: I was running a web service on azure that allowed me to read the database but I had to shut it down, too expensive for what I need

Comment: Well, whatever system is causing daily changes should probably host some server that you should pull data from. It's not really clear why you are dumping that into SQLite, then wanting to place that into Google Drive (or similar)

Answer (score 0):

SQLite databases are just files.

If you're using Google Drive to manage the database, you still have to store it *somewhere* so that you can access it as a file. And there's only external or internal storage where you could put it.

Comment: Thank you, thought as much but wa hoping for a miracle